# Android: Share Text & Image (URL) Via Intent

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-intent, share

I am trying to share text with an image via an ACTION_SEND intent.  The catch is that the image is represented by a URL, not a local URI.  The code I currently have is:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text); // <- String
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, url); // <- URL object
```

Now I've tried a few variations on this.  I've tried with setType("image/*"), I've tried parsing a Uri from the URL, I've tried passing the URL string itself, etc.  Nothing so far seems to work.  However, when sending to twitter I do see the text, just not the image.

Edit:
Apparently the original description was not helpful enough, so....when I launch the above intent it successfully opens a chosen application like Twitter, or Facebook, or Gmail, or Text Messaging, but an image appars in NONE of these apps.  The text appears in Twitter - I can't remember if the text appears elsewhere, but my focus at this moment is on the image part anyway.

Comment: "Nothing so far seems to work" is a rather uninformative description of your symptoms.

Comment: At least in terms of Facebook, they recommend using their SDK for sharing information on Facebook. I had trouble posting to Facebook via the ACTION_SEND intent in the past, so, I switched over to using their SDK. I heard they no longer support the Android ACTION_SEND intent but I'm not sure if that's true or not.

Comment: @AndroidStudent can you post a link to the Android library used to access the Facebook SDK?  Also, do you know if Twitter offers an analogous package?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/android-beta/

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to share on Facebook in that way because of Facebook's policy as it says in a [known bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423):

> API does not support pre-filling the message for users

Comment: I tried to submit an Android app recently that uses their SDK. The app shared image with pre-filled in, but still editable, text, and it got rejected when asking for `publish_actions` permission.  They simply don't allow this via Facebook app.

Answer (score -2):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");               
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,videoPos);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap));
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: You have asked similar question, please delete this answer.